# How to Shut Down RMI UnicastRemoteObject After Being Idle for N Seconds

Tags: java, rmi

I have an Application to which I am trying to add RMI capabilities.

Starting the Application is expensive, so I want to start the RMI server with the first client call, and shut down after a certain time of inactivity, say after 1 minute.

I start the server from the client, like so:

```
try {
  service = (RMIService) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:" + RMIServiceImpl.RMI_PORT + "/" + RMIServiceImpl.RMI_NAME);
}
catch (ConnectException ex) {
  new RMIServiceImpl(args);
  service = (RMIService) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:" + RMIServiceImpl.RMI_PORT + "/" + RMIServiceImpl.RMI_NAME);
}
```

and in RMIServiceImpl I have

```
try {

    rmiRegistry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(RMI_PORT);
    rmiRegistry.rebind(RMI_NAME, this);

    System.out.println("Registered  RMI Service " + RMI_NAME + " on port " + RMI_PORT);
}
catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }

long idle = 1000 * 60;
long lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis();  // updated with each client call
do {
    try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < (lastCall + idle));

if (rmiRegistry != null)
    rmiRegistry.unbind(RMI_NAME);  // (1)

UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(this, true);  // (2)
```

the problem is that the RMIServiceImpl never exits and the JVM keeps on running.

at point (1) I get a NotBoundException, which I'm not sure why because that name is bound?

at point (2) I get a WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader

but in either case the service does not shut down...

Any ideas?  TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Have your remote object implement the `Unreferenced` interface, and unexport it in the `unreferenced()` method implementation, with

```
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(this, true);
```

This will kick in at the expiration of the DGC interval.

Comment: thank you for the answer, to clarify: the remote object is RMIServiceImpl?  I added Unreferenced to it but the unreferenced() method is never called.  What am I missing?  thanks!

Comment: Then the object is newer unreferenced. For example, it may be bound in he registry, or a client may still have a stub for it that's reachable in the GC sense. In such a case it would be invalid to unexport the remote object, as it would cause a NoSuchObjectException in the client next time it used the stub.